# Why does permutation of statements in SQL results in an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Leetcode, for the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/big-countries/, if I give this solution:

```
SELECT
    name,
    population,
    area
FROM
    World
WHERE
    25000000 < population OR 3000000 < area;
```

The execution is correct.

However, this solution:

```
FROM
    World
SELECT
    name,
    population,
    area
WHERE
    25000000 < population OR 3000000 < area;
```

returns an error.

Why is that ? I though the order was irrelevant, as the SQL server will determine the order of execution itself. The second ordering is also closer to the logical order of execution as described at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement .

Comment: SQL is declarative and expects keywords in a certain order.  Your second version will not run on any version of SQL of which I'm aware.

Comment: This Leetcode problem doesn't say that the code is dedicated for SQL Server, there are dozens of other database management systems and they would understand only the first variant, which is a standard SQL

Comment: So what are the constraints on the clauses in a SELECT statement ? Is there an order to follow for the clauses, or are they just conventions ?

Comment: 's there an order to follow for the clauses' - yes there is and you should remind yourself of them by reading the manual.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: How the query is executed, is up to the database engine. The query itself however, needs a particular syntax

Comment: I guess the thing that is confusing you is that the `SELECT` part is logically executed after the rest of the query, and before `ORDER BY` or `TOP/OFFSET`. But the syntax mandates you put `SELECT` first. This is why I often start writing queries as `SELECT * FROM...` then go back and change the `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a very specific language.  Part of the language is the `SELECT` statement, which consists of a variety of clauses.

Common clauses are:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `ORDER BY`

Of these clauses, the `SELECT` is required.  The `FROM` is required in some databases, and the rest are optional.  Each clause then has its own syntax.

The SQL language defines the *ordering* of the clauses within a statement; the ordering is fixed.  *Any other ordering results in a syntax error*.

This is how the language is defined.  You might as well ask why Japanese word order doesn't work in English.  That is just not how English is defined.